# Trying to understand asyncio.gather() in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I was trying to understand and test a simple code

```
async def func(inp: str) -> str:
    time.sleep(5)
    print(inp)
    return inp

async def run():
    k = await asyncio.gather(*[lol(inp=n) for n in "123"])
    k = [n for n in k]
    print(k)

asyncio.run(run())
```

OUTPUT

```
1
2
3
['1', '2', '3']
```

But I see 5 seconds difference between printing 1, 2 and 3. **Aren't all supposed to be working async shouldn't I be getting 1,2 and 3 around the same time?**

Comment: Use `asyncio.sleep(5)` ?

Comment: Aaaah, so everything inside async should be async as well. Makes sense. thanks